# How to swap non-copyable elements in a vector?

Tags: string, vector, rust, swap

I would like to swap `String` elements of a vector

```
let mut v_sa: Vec<String> = vec![];
...
let temp_a = v_sa_ib[j];
v_sa_ib[j] = v_sa_ib[j+1];
v_sa_ib[j+1] = temp_a;
```

It works with integers but not with `String`s. I also tried to create a second vector `temp_b` (same type of `temp_a`) and to populate it instead of swapping but i got always the same error: `the type of this value must be known in this context`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: how about a vector of string references and just change the references?

Comment: tried but no success

Comment: Error: cannot move out of indexed content

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the [`swap()` method of `Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.swap) to swap two elements directly:

```
v_sa_ib(j, j+1);
```

There is also a generic swap function called [`std::mem::swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html) but it is difficult to use here because obtaining two mutable references two different elements of the same `Vec` is quite involved.

The reason why it worked with integers is that integers implement the `Copy` trait, so Rust can automatically create new copies.